# Do I need to install apache2-mpm-worker libapache2-mod-fcgid php5-cgi like I used to in previous versions of Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, apache2, lamp

I'm installing Ubuntu 14.04 from Amazon EC2 AMI.

When installing Apache MPM worker in older releases of Ubuntu, the following packages were required:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2-mpm-worker libapache2-mod-fcgid php5-cgi
```

After installing LAMP on Ubuntu 14.04 I noticed that mpm_worker is already under /etc/apache2/mods-available/

Do I need to still install those packages above or enabling the worker by "a2enmod mpm_worker" is all I need to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `apache2-mpm-worker`, no, you do not need to install this package, as the package now includes just a doc file.

For `libapache2-mod-fcgid` and `php5-cgi`, you still may need to install these packages. The `libapache2-mod-fcgid` package adds a mod file and an HTML and XML file, while the `php5-cgi` package installs a conf file and an executable.

I would suggest trying to enable and use the mod first before installing the other packages.

Comment: Thanks, it helped. Decided not to use mod_fcgid.